# Why can't I get my Firefox bookmarks to open in a new tab?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, tabs

I've been looking into to this frustrating tweaks alot and have yet to find an answer.  There is an add-on that supposed make it possible to open a bookmark in a new tab (rather than over a current open tab/page) but it doesn't work (might not be up to date with latest version).  Any help would be truly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: I use TabMixPlus, which gives almost total over what opens where and when, including what you want.

Comment: Thanks AFH.  I've downloaded this and gone through the preferences but I must be be missing something as my bookmarks are still not opening in new tabs.  Can you take a look and let me know what you think is the appropriate pref to make this happen.  Thanks!

Comment: or press CMD (on OSX) or CTRL (Window, Linux) while clicking the bookmarked link :) - works out of the box

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the TabMixPlus plugin in Firefox.
2. Open TabMixPlus Options.
3. In the **Events** tab, select the **Tab Opening** sub-tab.
4. In the **Open tabs from:** section select ALL of the types of content you'd like to open in a new tab.